# CDO works in VBScript, but doesn't work in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, vbscript

I have a VBScript file to send the emails It works fine, but when I created a C# program (.Net 4.5) with the same CDO settings I got

> The transport failed to connect to the server.

Please check what is the problem with my C#.

VBScript:

```vb
Dim objMessage
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

objMessage.Subject = Subj 
objMessage.From = Sender
objMessage.To = Receivers

objMessage.TextBody = Body 

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = ServerName

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 2

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = ""
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = ""
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

objMessage.Send
```

C#:

```cs
using System.Net.Mail;
...
CDO.Message  objMessage   = new CDO.Message();

objMessage.Subject = Subj;
objMessage.From = Sender;

objMessage.To = Receivers;
objMessage.TextBody = Body;

ADODB.Field FieldSMTPSendUsing = objMessage.Configuration.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"];
FieldSMTPSendUsing.Value = 2;

ADODB.Field FieldSMTPServer = objMessage.Configuration.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"];
FieldSMTPServer.Value = ServerName; 

ADODB.Field FieldSMTPServerPort = objMessage.Configuration.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"];
FieldSMTPServerPort.Value = 25;

ADODB.Field FieldSMTPconnectiontimeout = objMessage.Configuration.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout"];
FieldSMTPconnectiontimeout.Value =  60 ;

ADODB.Field FieldSMTPauthenticate = objMessage.Configuration.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"];
FieldSMTPauthenticate.Value = 2;

ADODB.Field FieldSMTPsendusername = objMessage.Configuration.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername"];
FieldSMTPsendusername.Value = "";

ADODB.Field FieldSMTPsendpassword = objMessage.Configuration.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword"];
FieldSMTPsendpassword.Value = "";

ADODB.Field FieldSMTPusessl = objMessage.Configuration.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl"];
FieldSMTPusessl.Value = false;

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update();

objMessage.Send();
```

Comment: You aren't using CDO in your C# code.

Comment: Could you explain, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CDO in C#. Use the [`MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for composing messages, and the [`SmtpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for sending them.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(Sender, Receivers, Subj, Body);

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ServerName);

try {
  client.Send(message);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine("Cannot send message.");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what's wrong with CDO ? We used it for ages in VBA/VBS/VB6.

Comment: You can't tell from comparing the two code snippets?

Comment: Afriad - no
As of  now CDO is our recommended mailing method

Comment: Anyway , the test run of

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(MailSender ,,MailReceivers); 
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); 
            client.Port = 25; 
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
            client.Host = OurServer ; 
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", ""); 
            mail.Subject = "this is a test.";  
            mail.Body = "test email body"; 
            client.Send(mail);
produced
Failure sending mail

Comment: Works fine for me after I removed the duplicate comma in the first statement. You did define that you're using the `System.Net.Mail` namespace, didn't you.

Comment: Duplicate come - is an Copy-Paste-Fix error.  <br>  I used 1 coma & system.Net.Mail. w/o them I couldn't compile. and I got non-informative Failure sending mail

Comment: Anyway I cannot understand why VBS  CDO works (tested 5 minutes ago) and C# CDO with the supposedly same settings doesn't work